# how to install tensorflow-gpu 2.6.0 error with numpy?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, installation, pip, anaconda3

I am trying to install and use tensorflow-gpu, i installed Cuda..etc
then i installed tensorflow-gpu package using anaconda navigator GUI in an isolated environment
the latest available version of `tensorflow-gpu is 2.6.0` in anaconda navigator, `numpy version 1.25.2`

> Windows 11 Gpu : Nvidia geforce RTX 3060

When I try to import tensorflow i get the following error, what should i do ?

**ERROR**:

```
**\anaconda3\envs\deeplearninggpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:585: FutureWarning: In the future `np.object` will be defined as the corresponding NumPy scalar.
  np.object,


AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

I thought it might be conflicting with numpy version so i tried downgrading with anaconda navigator GUI but i always get issue with installing an older version of numpy,

i tried to use pip to upgrade to a more recent version of tensorflow as well, but that created more errors,

Comment: The issue is related to the version of Numpy being used. Tensorflow 2.60 might have compatibility issues with Numpy 1.25.2.
Please update the Numpy version with Tensor flow 2.60. and kindly follow this link [Tensorflow-Gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) to install tensor flow-gpu and follow the step by step instructions to  install required hardware and software requirements.